# Limits (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\displaystyle\lim_{z->z_0}f(z)=L$. Prove that if $L\neq 0$, then there exists $\eta>0$ such that for all z in the domain of the definition of $f$ with $z\in N_{\eta}(z_0)$, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}|L|<|f(z)|.$$

I know the definition of limits in complex analysis which is, $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $z\in D_f$ with $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$, we have $|f(z)-L|<\epsilon$.

But i dont know what to do next. I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you struggling with?

Comment: Could you prove the exact same statement in real analysis ?

Comment: @David I edited it sir.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe no sir.

Comment: @Instructor'sAccount Then, begin to do it with a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ : it should be easier since you can more easily draw the situation in the real case. Then you will be able to realise that the complex case has no difference with the real one.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I still dont get it why solving it in the real case will make it easier. Im really sorry. Im a newbie on this topic.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe If you can give me some hints, it would be very helpful.

Comment: @Instructor'sAccount $\bullet\ $First step, prove the following statement : let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x)= 2$. Prove that there exists $\eta > 0 $ such that for all $x \in ]x_0 - \eta, x_0 + \eta[$, $|f(x)| > 1$. $\quad \bullet\ $
Second step will be to prove the exact same statement where you replace $2$ by $L \neq 0$ and $1$ by $L/2$.$\quad \bullet\ $
Third step will be to prove that the proof of the second step also works in the complex case.

Comment: Use the definition for the case $\epsilon = \frac{|L-f(x)|}{2}$. Can you continue from there?